# Sluggish Postfix Performance: Can't locate cause of 1s delay when queueing messages

Tags: performance, postfix, email

We'd like to deploy a high-volume SMTP server (double opt-in lists), but discovered two of our Ubuntu servers take about 1s to send a single message.

When sending an email by hand, the delay occurs after closing off the data section of the message (between L#3 & L#4, see below) and appears to us as if Postfix is sluggish in adding the item to the active queue.

```
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Message goes here
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 0DB032015E
```

I'm not familiar with Postfix and would appreciate any help. Our servers are a freshly installed pair of Ubuntu 9.10 boxes with RAID1 drives that report about 60mb/sec with hdparam. We've fooled around with settings like in_flow_delay, but arne't having much luck.

### Additional Information

Thanks for the tips. It appeared that disk speed was a limiting factor for other people, so I wanted to cover that first.

As for DNS, the server is setup with a proper FQDN and reverse. No DNS server to begin with, and bind setup as a local caching server hasn't improved much. And as a note, I do notice a line in the log reading: delay=0.79, if that gives anyone any ideas.

#### postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
debug_peer_list = octane.to
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = inferno.octane.to.local, octane.to.local, localhost
myhostname = inferno.octane.to
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

#### mail.log, cleaned up

```
smtpd[3413]: improper command pipelining after HELO from localhost[127.0.0.1]
smtpd[3413]: 3CFEB20160: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
cleanup[3417]: 3CFEB20160: message-id=<20091118231505.3CFEB20160@inferno.octane.to>
qmgr[3392]: 3CFEB20160: from=<tyler@octane.to>, size=360, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
smtpd[3413]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 220 hotrod.octane.to ESMTP Sendmail 8.13.8/8.13.8; Wed, 18 Nov 2009 18:15:05 -0500
smtp[3418]: > mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: EHLO inferno.octane.to
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 250-hotrod.octane.to Hello inferno.octane.to [76.74.234.11], pleased to meet you
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 250-PIPELINING
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 250-8BITMIME
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 250-SIZE
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 250-DSN
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 250-ETRN
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 250-DELIVERBY
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 250 HELP
smtp[3418]: server features: 0x900f size 0
smtp[3418]: Using ESMTP PIPELINING, TCP send buffer size is 4096
smtp[3418]: > mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: MAIL FROM:<tyler@octane.to> SIZE=360
smtp[3418]: > mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: RCPT TO:<test@octane.to> ORCPT=rfc822;test@octane.to
smtp[3418]: > mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: DATA
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 250 2.1.0 <tyler@octane.to>... Sender ok
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 250 2.1.5 <test@octane.to>... Recipient ok
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
smtp[3418]: > mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: .
smtp[3418]: > mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: QUIT
smtp[3418]: < mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25: 250 2.0.0 nAINF5wx003171 Message accepted for delivery
smtp[3418]: 3CFEB20160: to=<test@octane.to>, relay=mail.octane.to[76.74.234.28]:25, delay=0.79, delays=0.45/0/0.04/0.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 nAINF5wx003171 Message accepted for delivery)
smtp[3418]: name_mask: resource
smtp[3418]: name_mask: software
qmgr[3392]: 3CFEB20160: removed
```

#### Checking two machines -- screencast

I have two machines with near identical configurations. Setup Ironhide, a clone of Inferno (the machine that's giving me problems.). Here's a screencast walking through a batch deployment, logs and some basic configuration.

Screencast ((Link Removed))

Comment: "double opt-in" is spammer-speak.

Comment: Cranking up the logging and including what those say during/around the delay would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Unless other symptoms on the box in question point to IO, I'm not sure why you're checking the hard drives and related config.

My first guess is DNS-related, as everything postfix does as an MTA is tied to DNS.  However, guessing is not very productive - perhaps showing us your current settings would be helpful.  Run the following command:

```
# postconf -n
```

And paste the output for those reading this question - obviously sanitise as necessary, the Internet being what it is.  FYI, per the postconf man page, the -n flag prints "*parameter settings that are not left at their built-in default value, because they are explicitly specified in main.cf*"

@womble: "double opt-in" is also Marketing-speak.

**UPDATE**

From the screencast, only thing of interest I noted was the "delays=" bit in the logs.  According to the release notes:

`Postfix logs additional delay information as "delays=a/b/c/d" where a=time before queue manager, including message transmission; b=time in queue manager; c=connection setup time including DNS, HELO and TLS; d=message transmission time.`

Seems messages from **inferno** have the largest portion of their delay in **a**, whereas messages from **ironhide** have theirs in **d**... which according to the notes above translates as inferno's message spending the majority of its time *before* the queue manager (including message transmission), and ironhide's message spending the majority of its time *in* message transmission.

Not sure what this means, but hope it helps in your search. :)

Comment: Without timestamps in your log snippet, it's difficult to theorise, but I would suggest getting a larger sampling of mails, sending to various MX servers, to see if the problem originates within your own network or not.

And the `delay=xx` is the measurement in seconds of the amount of time spent inside the postfix queue.  0.79 seems okay for a single message - would the average of many different recipients be higher or lower?

Comment: I'm leaning towards a networking issue, but I can't discover what for the life of me would simply delay the messages. I've added a link to a screen cast to the message, that's my last straw for troubleshooting...

Comment: FYI, due to character limit in comments, added feedback to my original "answer"... hth.